# How can I simulate Microsoft Surface tear-down timeout?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I've been developing an app for Windows 8 and can test Suspend, Resume, Shutdown, etc. from Visual Studio 2012. However, when I test the app on a Microsoft Surface, there is one other state I can't seem to simulate.

When an app is open and you leave the Surface untouched for a bit, the screen will dim and then eventually shut-off. If I wait long enough, maybe 1 or 2 minutes, and hit the start button, it will take me to the Lock Screen, where I can sign in. Once I sign in, it will show my app where I left it. However, after 1 second, it crashes immediately, and the Surface takes me back to the Start Screen.

I cannot simulate this using Visual Studio and the Simulator. Suspending/Resuming using Debug Location does not recreate this.

I looked at the event log on the Surface and found that my app was crashing with the following:

```
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 

Exception Info: System.Exception Stack: at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext+Invoker.<InvokeCore>b__0(System.Object) at
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object) at
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I have no clue how to find this. I am handling all unhandled exceptions with a standard message box, but it's not showing up. We've been very good at avoiding "async void" and making sure everything has "async Task" and awaited properly. So, I'm a bit stuck. I can't find where this is happening.

Anyone know how I can simulate this, or at least make the Event Log more verbose?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I would add some logging in your load/save and navigate methods. I assume you are using LayoutAwarePage as your base - if so you can override `LoadState`, `SaveState`, `OnNavigatedTo`, and `OnNavigatedFrom`. The logs will  at least give you an idea of what is happening in your app before the crash.

Comment: Thanks @chuex. I tried everything in the page events/states, but no luck. This is something deep in the framework. I'm sure I will learn something valuable once I figure this out :)

Comment: Are you by chance using any timers in your app, like `DispatcherTimer`? The timer is suspended when my app is not on screen, and then is fired immediately when I switch back to my app. Just something else to check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

There is an issue with the `MediaElement` control and volume. When the app is reactivated as I explain above, we get notified that the volume has changed. But for some reason, if we try to manipulate `MediaElement.Volume` when the app reactivates, it throws an exception. This exception does not have a message, just some strange hex number.

This only happens on the tablet, and it's very hard to detect. Essentially, for all of you who play media files, you should try/catch it like this:

```
try
{
   myMediaElement.Volume = .3;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // I don't really know what to do here.
   // but at least my app doesn't crash anymore :)
}
```

Anyway, thank you @JerryNixon and @chuex for helping out.

Comment: What's the strange hex number? My guess is that it's an HRESULT, which would give a further clue as to what may be going on.

Comment: @RaymondChen, "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D4E86"

Comment: A quick [Web search for the error code `0xC00D4E87`](http://www.bing.com/search?q=0xC00D4E87) shows that the error code means "The audio playback device is no longer present." What is presumably happening is that the audio device went offline due to loss of power, so when your app resumes, it needs to reacquire it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you have everything you need to test your scenario. But you may not be aware that you can remotely debug your app on a Surface just like it was running locally. As a result, you can proceed through your use case and let Visual Studio catch the exception:

It's easy. Here's a walkthrough: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/10/26/remote-debugging-windows-store-apps-on-surface-arm-devices.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, but unfortunately remote debugging does not simulate this. When the Surface dims and shuts-off the screen, after a while, Visual Studio will tell me it has lost the connection to the remote device and debugging stops. I'm resorting to brute-force debugging, where I'm removing everything and slowly re-introducing the pieces until I find the culprit.

Comment: I see. Sorry this is happening. Nothing in the logs? You are going to need to step through in your mind, then. What fires when the resume occurs. I can't really help you with specifics, but you could write out to a file (like local folders) and do some debugging like that. It is almost certainly in your Resuming or Activated or Loaded or some method like that. Then again, maybe it has to do with serialization. Perhaps a few more `try {} catch {}` might help you identify it. Wrap whole pages in a try if you want (for testing of course).